# Dovecot not serving all messages through IMAP

Tags: imap, dovecot

I have a Debian / Dovecot / Postfix standard setup. Additionally I am running notmuchmail indexer to quickly search for messages. As a mail client I use emClient on Windows, I also got Rainloop Webmail running.

I used notmuchmail to search for a particular message and i found it, received around 5 years ago. When I check with emClient, the messages dated back only until 3 1/2 years ago. First I suspected emClient to not have downloaded all messages, but then, checking with Rainloop, I also saw the oldest message visible via IMAP is 3 1/2 years old.

Searching the problem, it is suggested to resyncronize the mail client by deleting the dovecot-uidlist in my Maildir (https://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2013-October/092803.html), which i did. emClient resynced all messages accordingly BUT nothing changed, the oldest message is 3 1/2 years old.

So now i am at a loss... Is there anything else i can do to have access to ALL my messages through IMAP. My Server is running Dovecot 2.2.13.

output "of dovecot -n"

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian 8.9
login_trusted_networks = 192.168.1.0/24
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
  separator = /
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = " imap sieve"
quota_full_tempfail = yes
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = username
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/a.b.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_cipher_list = AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/a.b.com/privkey.pem
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol lda {
  info_log_path =
  log_path =
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
```

Comment: Please provide information on your configuration (`doveconf -n`) and check your mail log for relevant information. Also have a look at differences in file ownership/permissions.

Comment: Is there a guide what the permissions should be?
cant seem to find it here: https://wiki.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir
and this doesnt apply since its not a shared mailbox: https://wiki.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes/Permissions

Comment: So there is nothing that seems to be related in the mail.err or mail.log, the permissions of the particular message that doesnt show up is the same as others that DO show up: 
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser 10395837 Oct  6  2013

Comment: There is no general guideline, Dovecot must be able to access the mail (but access mode should not be too permissive, either). The actual required permissions depend on the configuration, but any _differences_ between messages that show up and others that do not would indicate a likely issue. If they're the same, you're probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Broken Indexes and Other Mailbox Issues

This sounds like an issue with a broken mailbox index, which is something Dovecot's usually very good at fixing on its own. In case it fails, you can force Dovecot to repair indexes and other issues using

```
doveadm force-resync -u <username> <mailbox>
```

in case of the user `johndoe` and mails not showing up in his inbox, the command would be

```
doveadm force-resync -u johndoe INBOX
```

Running `doveadm -Dv force-resync ...` (debug and verbose output) might provide more insight on any issues.

### Client Side Issues

In rare cases, mail clients might suffer under inconsistent local data, especially when mails have been renumbered on the server side due to mailbox issues. Some mail clients know "repair" functions, other might require you to remove and recreate the mailbox and thus trigger a full sync.